# Django: Stop redirecting URL to another page after setting it with permanent=True

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-urls

For some reason in my Django app, I used a redirect path as in my urls.py file, such that whenever someone visits example.com they would be redirected to example.com/blog

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls', namespace='blog')),
    path('', lambda request: redirect('blog/', permanent=True)),
]
```

Now I have constructed my site fully and added views for example.com.
In order to visit that page I removed the line that redirects path from my code base so that it no longer redirects to /blog whenever I try to visit example.com.

```
path('', lambda request: redirect('blog/', permanent=True))
```

But the problem is that I'm still being redirected to /blog even after removing that above line.

The same problem persist to me even in entirely new django project.
i.e. Even if I run another django project i can't visit "/" path it keeps being redirected to "/blog/".
I think it is happening due to some thing related with permanent=True.
Any help would be appreciated in reversing that effect.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a permanent redirect. It can be cached and by the standard the Browser can even update bookmarks. Use temporary redirects for this purpose, check your bookmarks and empty the browser cache.

Comment: The thing is I have already did that. Now I want to reverse the effect caused by that and I thought that just by removing that line I would have fixed it but it didn't. Can u guide me ?

Comment: Have you cleared your cache or disabled it ?

Comment: Oops! It was just a cache problem. Thanks

Comment: And by the way, by setting permanent flag to true, does it mean that store it in cache ? And how long does it last ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flag `permanent=True` implies that your webserver returns a `301 - Permanent Redirect` when someone tries to access the *index* page. You probably should have avoided using it and let the webserver return a `302 - Temporary Redirect`.

Status `301` means that the resource (page) is moved permanently to a new location. The client (browser) should not attempt to request the original location but use the new location from now on.

Status `302` means that the resource is temporarily located somewhere else, and the client (browser) should continue requesting the original URL.

Try not to remove the whole line but adjust it like as follow

```
path('', views.index, name='index')
```

Try also to test it in incognito mode, or disabling the cache.

Comment: Thanks. After I saw my code working in incognito I understood it was something to do with cache. As soon as I cleared my cache, I saw my page without being redirected.

Answer (score 1):

I use **Google Chrome**.

When setting **"permanent=True"** to your **Django Project**, the permanent redirect is cached by **Google Chrome** whether or not [**disabling cache for Google Chrome**](https://www.technipages.com/google-chrome-how-to-completely-disable-cache).

And, just by removing **"permanent=True"** from your **Django Project**, you cannot remove the cache of the permanent redirect from **Google Chrome**.

So, you must delete the cache from **Google Chrome** by following [**this instruction**](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop).